# Angular 2 to-do app not storing new tasks in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, angular, ionic2

I'm doing [this tutorial using Ionic 2 and Angular 2 to create a to-do app](https://www.udemy.com/ionic-2-rc0-kickstart-build-a-mobile-app-in-no-time/). I swear I am typing in the exact code he gives us in the video, but my app isn't storing items to the database. (The MySQL database is running just fine.) When it tries, I get this error:

```
Response_body: "failed"
headers: Headers
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: 2
url: "http://localhost/note/store.php"
__proto__: Body
it fails!   home.ts:25
```

and "[object Object]" in console.log. So the request is getting somewhere, but it's not getting saved for some reason and I can't tell why.

The teacher (tutor? Tutorialer?) looked at my detail.ts and said he couldn't see a post function going to store.php. My understanding is that this function in home.ts does that:

```
  addDB(obj){
    this.http.post("http://192.168.1.162/note/store.php",obj).
    subscribe(data =>{
      console.log(data);
      var resp = data.text().trim();
      if(resp == "success"){
        console.log("it works!");
        this.loadDB();
      }else{
        console.log("it fails!");
      }
    }, err=>{
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```

but when I said so, he didn't seem clear on what he needed anymore. I thought maybe StackOverflow would know what to do.

There are multiple .ts and .html and .php files, so I couldn't make a fiddle; [I've put them all up on GitHub instead](https://github.com/danicastone/danicassecondapp). Specifically, [home.html and home.ts](https://github.com/danicastone/danicassecondapp/tree/master/src/pages/home),  [app.module.ts](https://github.com/danicastone/danicassecondapp/tree/master/src/app), [detail.html and detail.ts](https://github.com/danicastone/danicassecondapp/tree/master/src/pages/detail), and [these php files](https://github.com/danicastone/danicassecondapp/tree/master/database) are really the only ones I have touched.

I feel like this has to be something simple and ridiculous like "this function is in the wrong file and you didn't notice he switched which one he was using right here" but I swear I've looked over it repeatedly....

Comment: With nothing to debug, i can guess where the error is, subscribe is not function of http utility of node, subscribe is some other method of service worker api that the source code is using. or may be the node js server(angular) started to some other urls domain(http://192.168.1.162/ or http://192.168.1.161/). both urls are not same http://localhost/note/store.php and http://192.168.1.162/note/store.php

Answer (score 3):

When using http in angular 2, you would have to parse the response using a .map() function like so :

```
this.http.post("http://192.168.1.162/note/store.php",obj)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data=>{

    },
    err=>{

    })
```

EDIT : Using Promises instead of observable :

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

this.http.post("http://192.168.1.162/note/store.php",obj)
    .toPromise()
    .then(data=>{

    })
    .catch(err=>{

    })
```

Comment: That worked! to get rid of that error message... but now I'm getting 

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (body.js:22)
    at MapSubscriber.project (home.ts:19)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:77)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (xhr_backend.js:72)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:227)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at e.runTask (polyfills.js:3)`

Comment: sadly, home.ts:19 is just the `.map(res => res.json())` and I can't find any rogue i's in the code; there are a number of places where it's used as a variable but I went through and switched them all out for other letters one by one to see if changing any of them would change the error message, and no luck.

Comment: What is the response data that you are sending from your backend?

Comment: It should just be the text in the description and title of a "to do" list item. 

The teacher argues, "We only use .map() when the response is in json format. In our php, we are actually returning a string, which is either "success" or "failed" right ? So perhaps remove the .map but just .subcribe() it, then the response you do resp.text().trim() to get the body of the response." Except that still leaves me with the initial problem of it failing to post to store.php.... And the data being parsed here is the to-do item, not the "success" or "failed" that gets sent to console.log....

Comment: Okay in that case..can you try using promises instead of observable for the http request?

Comment: @DanicaStone Please check the EDIT for using promises

Comment: Thank you!! That did work to eliminate the syntax error, but now I am back to "it fails!" I downloaded the teacher's code and his doesn't work either -- which makes sense, since it ought to be the same code, but I did notice some places where he had lines of code in his video that he had omitted to tell us to put in. So I had thought maybe he had included something that made it work but accidentally left it out of the video. No such luck. Maybe there's something that has recently changed in Ionic 2 or Angular 2 that broke his code?

Comment: update: did some php/sql research and changed the if/else statement in store.php so that instead of just echoing the useless "it fails!" it instead echoes `"Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);` so I'm actually getting the useful error message 
`"Error: INSERT INTO note2 (title,description) VALUES ('test', 'test') Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'"`

Comment: When I try to insert in myPHPadmin instead, I get the same error and it shows that what it's actually doing is `INSERT INTO `note2` (`ID`, `title`, `description`, `imgurl`) VALUES ('', 'test', 'test', '')`. If I specify the ID in the values, it inserts just fine, so I'm guessing the darn thing isn't autoincrementing the primary key. I deleted the entire table and recreated it using mySQL instead of the GUI so I could set it to autoincrement, and everything works now!!!